# How to run EntityFeildQuery on all fields of a node that reference users (php)

Tags: php, drupal, entity, field

Is there a way to run EntityFieldQuery on all fields of a node that reference a user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question on stackexchange, I don't have a 50+ reputation otherwise would have just added a comment. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60290/query-custom-node-by-user-entity-reference.

Comment: Yes this is a similar question, but I EntityFieldQuery will only run on /one/ field, and I am looking for a way to run it on all fields (that make reference to a user).